# Primeng data table limit the max 4 row selectable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm using angular 11 with primeng library.
Objective is to select max 4 records and show comparison on dialogue box.
Using <p-tableCheckboc for row selection.
But chalenge is there is no arrangment for limiting the max no of row selection.
Either you select one record or multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look over the `selection` property. It might help you implement this custom behavior.

The primeng docs say that this property reflects the

> Selected row in single mode or an array of values in multiple mode.

So, in your case, since you allow multiple selections, `selection` will be an array of values. In this case, you could do something like this on your table rows:

```
[disabled] = "selection.length === numberOfMaxSelections"
```

Comment: But it will disable all the rows even the selected ones. User should be allowed to de select and reselect another record

Comment: Right, then you could move this condition in a getter and add this part to the condition: && !selection.includes(value) .. or something like that (it would basically make sure that you disable only rows that have a value not contained in the selection array)